# Referenciar uma table através de uma string em Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

Preciso utilizar uma table em Lua, mas só posso referenciá-la através de uma string, exemplo:

```
tabelaA = { "qualquer coisa" }
variavelA = "tabelaA"

print(variavelA)
resultado: "qualquer coisa"
```

Tendo em mente que não tenho como referenciar esta tabela diretamente, eu vou obter o nome em string.

Answer (score 2):

Existe a tabela `_G`, chamado de o [*ambiente global*](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/pt/manual.html#2.2), que representa as variáveis existentes:

```
> print(tabelaA[1])
qualquer coisa
> print(_G["tabelaA"][1])
qualquer coisa
```

---

Também, sempre pode construir outra tabela:

```
tabelaVariaveis = {}
tabelaVariaveis["tabelaA"] = tabelaA

-- e pode acrescentar mais
tabelaB = { "outra coisa" }
tabelaVariaveis["tabelaB"] = tabelaB
```

e utilizá-la:

```
> print(tabelaVariaveis["tabelaA"][1])
qualquer coisa
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, Dan Getz
Consegui utilizar exemplo, ajudou muito!

Comment: @arthurgps2 tentei a sua sugestão, mas `print(shared["tabelaA"][1])` não funcionou aqui (Lua 5.1.5). Favor, pode explicar mais?

Comment: Também existe [`_ENV`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.2). `_ENV` e `_G` são por padrão uma mesma tabela, só que `_ENV` é o mais principalmente usado pelo Lua, por exemplo, quando você tenta acessar um nome/identificador não local, o Lua pega o valor atual de `_ENV` e pega o campo com esse nome. Apenas Lua 5.2+ suporta `_ENV` (LuaJIT).